# Drupal Panels, Tabs - How do I create a link to a tab within a panel node?

Tags: drupal-6, tabs, drupal-panels

**How do I create a link to a tab within a panel node?**

I'm working on a Drupal website and have tabs within panel nodes (Modules: Tabs, Panels, Tabs Panel Style). When I click on the tabs it takes me to the correct tab. When I click on the 'next' and 'previous' links they take to the correct page. When I hover over those links they show me the link URL (ex: http://examplesite.com/content/Project-Template#build-it).

When I type in a URL like that in the address bar it doesn't take me to the tab, but it does take me to the main page with the tabs on it.

How do I create a link to a tab within a panel node?

This is very important b/c I want to be able to direct people to a certain tab from other pages. This will also be useful if I need to call one of the tabs but pass some parameters in this time (example: editing or deleting data, which passes parameters of what to edit or delete). I want the user to be brought back to the tab they made the request from and not the first tab b/c that is not user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you, it's for the 7.x-1.x branch.

https://drupal.org/node/2214435#comment-8560105

Comment: Thanks for the fix but I no longer use Drupal. I went back to Wordpress ... perhaps some day I will use Drupal again and this will prove to be useful to me.